# Can't get to alternate stage 3 in Castlevania: Rondo of Blood

Tags: psp, castlevania-dracula-x-chronicles

I can't find the passage to alternate stage 3.

I'm playing the PSP version of the game.

I've already looked at online FAQ and they haven't helped.

---

Yes sorry that wasn't clear, I can't figure out how to get to alternate stage 3

Comment: You can't figure out how to *get to alternate stage 3* or you're in *alternate stage 3 and can't find Tera?*

Answer (score 1):

You can only get to stage 3' from stage 2', and even then you'll have to follow a particular path.  The easiest way is to jump off the bridge at a special point, where the Ferryman will take you across the lake and you'll avoid fighting the stage boss:

This video's from the PSP version of the game, but he fights the boss instead of taking the shortcut:

[This page](http://www.chapelofresonance.com/games/rob/areas.html) has pictures along with a text walkthrough that might help.